# Web Application deployment status in tomcat

Tags: java, rest

I have java web application (.war) and deployed into application server (tomcat or any app server). I need to write a REST API which returns health check of that application or status of deployment of that application in server.

So my requirement something like,

```
http://<host>:<port>/myapp/healthcheck

response : {"status":"UP"}
```

How I can implement this feature. I have tried JavaMelody but I have not seen status or health check API in JavaMelody which return application deployment status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like wildfly's [health check](https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/advanced/monitoring.html).
That allows you to create JAXRS endpoints annotated with @Health and returning  status UP or DOWN depending on the app state.

```
@GET
@Path("/health")
@Health
public HealthStatus checkHealth() {
   return isMyAppOK() ? HealthStatus.up() : HealthStatus.down();
}
```

Other option can be [spring boot actuator](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) which exposes */health* endpoint to your spring boot application.

Comment: Thanks Jan, one confirmation needed that, wildfly's  is also check connectivity with third party application means my app also talk to kafka and RabbitMQ so I want to check that if my application loses the connectivity with these application, if yes then I need to add another parameter in response json that kafkaConn : down or rabbitConn : down